# Why is vanishing beta function associated with scale-invariance?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory, scale-invariance

Why is vanishing beta function associated with scale-invariance? Coupling constants  have change rate of zero at some scale, but how is that related to scale-invariance?

Association of vanishing beta function with scale-invariance also indicates that a theory that is not scale-invariant at some scale cannot have vanishing beta function. Would that be correct?

Comment: You have effective scale invariance at a zero of β, but not far from it. The invariance is w.r.t.  small/infinitesimal rescaling, not large ones. A theory with  vanishing β everywhere would have no need for it, and would be globally scale invariant. Are you concerned about N=4 super-YM?

Comment: Look at what happens for positive and negative beta. (keeping in mind what Cosmas said about being infinitesimal as well)